# import path issue when a package and the main use a common third package

Tags: go

I have several microservices written in golang, and wanted to provide some common services.  In this example, I have a common `go-restful` filter that does authorization of API calls. The compilation error indicates that the auth package and the main package are importing the underlying `go-restful` from different places.

Is there a nice way to resolve this without collapsing the code into one repository?

```
./main.go:104: cannot use AUTHZ.AuthorizeFilter() 
(type "github.com/Solinea/gsk-common/auth/vendor/github.com/emicklei/go-restful".FilterFunction) as type 
"github.com/Solinea/gsk-analytics/vendor/github.com/emicklei/go-restful".FilterFunction 
in argument to "github.com/Solinea/gsk-analytics/vendor/github.com/emicklei/go-restful".Filter
```

Comment: I think the issue your facing is not what you described since using common package from multiple other packages just works fine in Golang. Maybe it's an import clause issue, could you provide us a piece of your code (with the import clause and the function calls)?

Comment: Packages cannot safely use vendored packages exactly because of the issue you are facing. (Works fine for commands). You must use a shared go-restful or use a different mechanism/tool to pin version (if needed at all).

Comment: Thanks, I've found a workaround.  Basically removed the dependency on go-restful in the common package, and exposed something a little less complete than I had originally wanted, but still suitable.